# Removing 'local7' log entries from /var/log/messages

Tags: ubuntu, rsyslog

Using rsyslog.conf on Ubuntu -

The default line for /var/log/messages in 50-default.conf is:

```
*.*;auth,authpriv.none      -/var/log/syslog
```

I'm starting to log a lot of things at the local7 level - with a line like:

```
local7.*   /my/file/name
```

All of the local7 messages are showing up in /var/log/syslog, which of course is not what I want.  I can't quite nail the filter syntax to remove them...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add local7.none after authpriv.none.

The important thing is that local7.none (which excludes local7) comes after `*.*` (which includes local7) on the /var/log/syslog line.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
local7.*   /my/file/name

local7.* ~
```

well before the line that references syslog